# Username/Password lookup in Hashmap

Tags: java

So as a homework assignment I'm supposed to be able to accept both an username and a password, then lookup a Hashmap that's already been formed (from a FakePersonDatbase text document), to see if that username and password exist inside the Hashmap; the Hashmap's Key is a String which is the username and the value is an object called User, which is formed from the FakePersonDatabase.

This is my attempt at it, I started by creating the same method that's used to created the Hashmap in the Database class except changing the username and password in the object to the Strings that were entered in the beginning, and then from there I kind of get lost and don't know quite how to go about comparing the new User object to user_map.

This is the User class/object that's used in both in the Main and the Database class

```
public class User 
{
    public String first_name, last_name, email, country, username, password, ip; 

    public User(String[] parts)
    {
        first_name = parts[0];
        last_name = parts[1];
        email = parts[2];
        country = parts[3];
        username = parts[4];
        password = parts[5];
    }
}
```

This is the Database, that's used to create the user_map Hashmap.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Database 
{
    public static Map<String, User> load()
    {
        Map<String, User> user_map = new HashMap<String, User>();
        try 
        {
            Scanner data_store = new Scanner(new File("fake-people-db.txt"));           

            while (data_store.hasNextLine())
            {
                String[] split_string = data_store.nextLine().split(",");
                User u = new User(split_string);
                user_map.put(u.username, u);
            }                   
        } 

        catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return user_map;
    }
}
```

This is the main, which has been my attempt so far.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.*;

public class Gatekeeper 
{   
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        /* parse the user database */
        Map<String, User> user_map = Database.load();
        /* You now have a map full of users.
         * The key is the username and the value is the user object.
         * How can you check to see if the given username/password is correct? */
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter username");
        String username = keyboard.nextLine();

        if(user_map.containsKey(username))
        {
            System.out.println("Enter password");
            String password = keyboard.nextLine();

            Map<String, User> user_compare = new HashMap<String, User>();

            try 
            {
                Scanner data_store = new Scanner(new File("fake-people-db.txt"));

                while (data_store.hasNextLine())
                {
                    String[] split_string = data_store.nextLine().split(",");
                    split_string [4] = username;
                    split_string [5] = password;
                    User u = new User(split_string);
                        user_compare.put(u.username, u);
                        /* I have a feeling that this is where the issue is occuring, 
                         * I don't know how to compare the object created above to the user_map Hashmap.*/
                        if(u.equals(user_map.get(u.username)))
                        {
                            System.out.println("Hello");
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Incorrect password");
            } 

            catch (FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }           
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("That username does not exist.");
        }
    }
}
```

Apologies for the sophomoric looking code, I'm a CCC student barely learning the ropes. Any help with this would be much appreciated!

Comment: what the hack. your code doesn't show any of your intention. try to explain to yourself what each line is doing and compare the original target of the program. you shall see what's the problem of it.

Comment: From what I could understand the assignment is for getting an User object from the map, and them comparing the password inside this object against the one informed on the command line (this text may be a good hint on what you actually need to do).

Comment: Hint: If `user_map` already contains the in-memory version of the database, why to you feel you need to re-read the database in your code?

Comment: Parsing is for compilers. The term you need is 'lookup'. Don't misuse standard terminology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to compare the whole `User` object, you just want to validate if the password is the valid one for that user, right?

You can add a method to your `User` class:

```
 public boolean doesPasswordEqual(String password) {
     return this.password.equals(password);
 }
```

Then in your main, you can do:

```
...
System.out.println("Enter username");
String username = keyboard.nextLine();

if(user_map.containsKey(username))
{
   System.out.println("Enter password");
   String password = keyboard.nextLine();

   if (user_map.get(username).doesPasswordEqual(password)) {
       System.out.println("Hello");
   } else {
       System.out.println("Incorrect password");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
public class Gatekeeper 
{           
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Map<String, User> user_map = Database.load();

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String username,password;

        System.out.println("Enter username");
        username = keyboard.nextLine();

        if (!user_map.containsKey(username))
        {
            System.out.println("That username does not exist.");
            System.exit(0);
        }   

        System.out.println("Enter password");
        password = keyboard.nextLine();

        User un = user_map.get(username);

            if((un.password).equals(password))
            {
                System.out.println("Successfully logged in.");
                System.out.println("Welcome " + un.first_name + " "+ un.last_name);
            }
            else
                System.out.println("Incorrect password");
    }   
}
```